# Arrangements of INDEPENDENCE where 2 letters are between the $D's$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

> In how many arrangements between the letters of the word $\text{INDEPENDENCE}$ are there always 2 letters between the  2 $D's$?

$$$$
Any help with this question would be appreciated.

Comment: First arrange INEPENENCE, and then put the two D's in one of the 9 possible positions.

Comment: x @BetterWorld: I don't like the tone you're taking with me. Good luck finding someone who's willing to help you with that attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an arrangement of the desired form, you can permute INEPENENCE (25200 ways to do this, as you've computed), then insert the first (leftmost) D into the permuted INEPENENCE. There are 9 ways to insert the first D--before the first letter, or the second, or ... or the ninth; if you insert the first D anywhere else, you cannot satisfy the requirement of having two letters between the D's. Then there is no choice where the second D must go. So the total is $25200\times9=226800$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{10!}{3!\times 4!}$ 10 - letter perms without the Ds

There are 11 places to insert the first D but only the first 9 places allow you to follow the first D by two non D letters

so total perms = $9 \times\dfrac{10!}{3!\times 4!}=226800$